# optimal architecture for react redux 'two-way' binding

Tags: reactjs, redux

I know there is a high chance I'll get downvoted because it is not the question about the specific code but more a request for advice about optimal architecture in `react` + `redux`.

So the aim is to build a form (the code should be able to be  reused with other forms later, so it should be rather generic), that would be binded with the chat window. By *binding* I mean: users and chat bot can provide an input in chat window and it will change the form inputs. It is also valid the other way around: any change on a form input would trigger an 'input' in chat window so the bot is aware of what is going on with the filling in of the form.

I did a supersimple and rather stupid  vanilla JS example of what I mean here:
https://codepen.io/chapkovski/pen/PowGzVb

So when a user changes the input `inp1` to `"asdf"`, the chat window gets message: `inp1:asdf`. The other way around: if you type `inp2:fdsa`, the value of `inp2` will be changed to `fdsa`.

So here is the question: I have a feeling (since I am a total newbie in redux) that it should be done in redux if we build the entire app in react. So a change of any input in a form would change the global state, and this change in state will trigger some redux listeners (if I use the term correctly), that will put some input to a chat window. And the other way around.

But before diving into it, I wonder if there are any recommendations: is this the right way to go or there are more simple ways of doing this?

Comment: Yes that's right, the form info would be in Redux, then both the form and the chat window will be connected to the store, so when the store changes they get the new values. And both form and chat window can dispatch actions to change the store.